# Scam or not — money transfer in the same bank to my account

Tags: scams

A friend was deported and has money in account here in the us there in Nigeria and want me to open up account so that I can retrieve the money for them from his friend that is also on the account so that he will put the money in my account said o just need 25 us dollars to do do scam or not told me its just for deposits from his friend that's meandering his money

Comment: Is this a person you knew in real life, or just on line?

Comment: This is a scam.

Comment: This is a scam. It will start as $25, and will steadily increase. **Cut off all contact with any individual associated with this communication! They will continue to attempt to scam you. You must remain on high alert now that they have gotten this close to getting money from you!**

Comment: Unless you know these people personally (IRL), it is a scam (and even if you _do_, it could be). First clue? If "his friend" can arrange to get money from "your friend's" account to the one you open, they can just as easily get it to "your friend".

Comment: How exactly do people ask questions about Nigeria, money, and bank accounts and not have klaxons go off in their head?

Answer (score 2):

From what you have written, this is more likely a scam.